# Adding outlets to iPhone View

Tags: interface-builder, xamarin.ios

I am creating a custom iPhone View in MonoTouch through the interface builder in XCode (In monodevelop New File -> MonoTouch -> iPhone View).

When selecting a new iPhone View it creates an xib file, but no .h file is created, so how can I create outlets?

I usually drag an outlet from my label/button etc. to the .h file, but since it doesn't exist for this view, I don't know how to create the outlets.

Can someone point me in the right direction, since all articles on google are for the old versions, where outlets where created differently.

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting a new iPhone View it creates an xib file?" do you mean dragging a view from the library to the storyboard?

Comment: No, I mean in MonoDevelop: Add File -> MonoTouch -> iPhone View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you double-click a .xib in MonoDevelop, MonoDevelop will generate header files for your [Register]'d C# classes that subclass ObjC types and export them to a temporary Xcode project, where you can use Xcode to drag&drop Outlets and Actions.

Adding a new iPhone View file (.xib) does not auto-create any backing C# classes for you, it *just* creates the .xib, therefore MonoDevelop does not autogenerate any header files for you when you double-click the .xib.

When Xcode launches, you can manually create some Objective-C headers for this .xib and drag&drop outlets or actions to it (or you can create C# classes in MonoDevelop before double-clicking the .xib). When you switch back to MonoDevelop, MonoDevelop will "import" the header files, translating them into the equivalent C#.

While in Xcode, you can also add .xib's there and MonoDevelop will import those as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer jstedfast, but I have a few problems. I have created the XIB file in MonoTouch, but double clicking it doesn't give me any headerfiles I can attach the outlet to?

Comment: Header files aren't generated for .xib's, they are only generated for NSObject subclasses that you've created.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it again tonight, and get back to you if it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin documentation has a good [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/Hello_iPhone) on this.  There is a section for **Adding Outlets and Actions to the UI**  using Interface Builder in Xcode4

> **Adding an Outlet** In order to create the Outlet, use the following
>   procedure:
>
> 1. Determine for which control you want an Outlet.
> 2. Hold down the Control key on the keyboard, and then drag from the control to an empty space in your code file after the @interface
>      definition.

Comment: The issue is that the iPhone View only has a xib and not a 'regular' code file.